# Eliminate duplicate values in crystal report

Tags: report, crystal-reports-xi

I have this issue in Crystal Report. Appreciate your time and your help

For ID 1, there are 2 descriptions and 2 codes and 2 Users

After running query with inner join tables on ID, I have 9 records and group by ID

ID  | Description       | Code      | User

1   | H1                | A         | abc

1   | H1                | A         | xyz

1   | H2                | A         | abc

1   | H2                | A         | xyz

1   | H1                | B         | abc

1   | H1                | B         | xys

1   | H2                | B         | abc

1   | H2                | B         | xyz

How can I do it in Crystal Report: (eliminate duplicate ID)

/---------------------------/

ID: 1

Description:
H1

H2

Code: A B

User:

abc

xyz

/----------------------------/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a group by each column starting with ID and so on.

Answer (score 0):

File->report options->General settings->check the box for "select distinct records".